# How to get ip address from config file to use in io.connect('ip:port')

Tags: socket.io

```
var socket = io.connect('http://ip:port');
socket.on('connect', function(){});
socket.on('message', function(message) {
    some code..
}); 
socket.on('disconnect', function(){ });
```

Here i don't want to use hardcoded ip address.so i need to get from config file.suggest me to solve this one.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the IP/PORT in a config file on the server and then pass those variables to the frontend using the 'locals' function in expressjs.

This will make that information available to your view renderer, which in turn can write the data in your templates.

How best to set up your config file is really up to your specific use-case.

---

```
# Server Side
app.locals.hosts = {
  http: 'localhost:3000',
  file: 'localhost:3001',
  websocket: 'localhost:2000'
}
```

---

```
# Client Side (rendered via mustache)
var socket = io.connect('ws://#{hosts.websocket}');
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.is there any other option other than using expressjs?